# Change BackgroundTint of ImageView on Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an ImageButton which have a drawable background resource which is oval shape.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:angle="270"
        android:color="#FFFF0000" />

</shape>
```

Here is the ImageButton in XML:

```
  <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/c1"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            />
```

I need to change the color of the circle shape dynamically, this will be done by either change the backgroundTint property in the ImageButton or change the circle shape color.

**NOTE:
I have array of strings that stores a list of RGB colors i need to use these RGB colors.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just found the answer, it works as follow:
In my changeColors(int id) function

- Create ImageButton variable.
- Assign the passed id to the ImageButton variable.
- Define GradientDrawable variable to store the ImageButton background.
- Update the color of the background using GradientDrawable variable.
- Update the ImageButton to the new background.

This is the code:

```
  ImageButton circle;
        circle = (ImageButton) findViewById(id);
        GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle);
        drawable.setColor(Color.parseColor("color in format #FFFFFF");
        circle.setBackground(drawable);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
mImageView.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.my_color));
```

Or you can do better, to support versions pre LOLLIPOP:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 
{
    ColorStateList stateList = ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color));
    mImageView.setBackgroundTintList(stateList);
} 
else 
{  
    mImageView.getBackground().getCurrent().setColorFilter(
           new PorterDuffColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color), 
            PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
}
```

More about PorterDuffColorFilter [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuffColorFilter.html).

Comment: is there a way to pass RGB color as string instead of 
getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.my_color) ?

because i have a list of RGB stored in array of strings i need to use them

Comment: @Omar you'd better convert those RGB colors to int and pass it to the `getColorStateList(int)` method.

Comment: thanks, i used another method i have post it, appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You may use ImageView instead and use app:tint to set the tint color for the background drawable.

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="20dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:src="@drawable/circle"
app:tint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
```